# bootstrap sass error in vscode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

```
@import '../assets/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

.col-md {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

This is my code. 
It's very simple but It has some error like below in vscode

I can't understand. why does it has an error?

Is there someone who know this error?

```
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after ".col-md {": expected "}", was "{"
        on line 3 of sass/d:\xampp\htdocs\accommodation\theme\accommodation\css\theme.sass
>> .col-md { {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's import issue sass @import is not working properly at the moment with custom files.reference it like this:

```
@import “../assets/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap”;
```

> Official response from Jesse Haff
>   You can `@import` SCSS or CSS files by adding an underscore to the beginning of the `scss/css` filename, and leaving the underscore and file extension off when importing it into your stylesheet. 
>   For example: 
>   Name your stylesheet something like: _stylesheet.scss. 
>   Then in theme.scss, reference it like this: 
>   `@import “stylesheet”`;